# How to auto stop the query if it takes a long time to execute?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have one collection called Audit Trail. This collection is to collect all the sender and admin actions. As for now has more than 50K data

```
const auditSchema = mongoose.Schema({
who: {
    type: String
},
what: {
    type: String
},
when: {
    type: Date
},
who_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
who_type: {
    type: String
}
});
```

I notice that some of the admins may accidentally search the audit trail from day one until now. So this will make my server down due to the huge data.

Is that any way to let MongoDB auto stop the query when the query has run more than 1 minute?

So far I have a solution for the frontend. Is that any solution that I can apply in backend?

Node JS: v12.22.5

MongoDB: v3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

**maxTimeMS**

The maxTimeMS() method sets a time limit for an operation. When the operation reaches the specified time limit, MongoDB interrupts the operation at the next interrupt point.

Terminate a Query
From
mongosh
, use the following method to set a time limit of 60000 milliseconds is equivalent to 1 minute for this query:

```
db.location.find( { "town": { "$regex": "(Pine Lumber)",
                              "$options": 'i' } } ).maxTimeMS(60000)
```

**Terminate a Command**

Consider a potentially long running operation using distinct to return each distinct collection field that has a city key:

```
db.runCommand( { distinct: "collection",
                 key: "city" } )
```

You can add the maxTimeMS field to the command document to set a time limit of 45 milliseconds for the operation:

```
db.runCommand( { distinct: "collection",
                 key: "city",
                 maxTimeMS: 45 } )
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried your first solution. But it doesn't working